# How to get key with value given to key in firebase in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Images from the firebase

image1:   [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nUEo.png)
above image has parent:"products"
and child:"color","description"
image2:   [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Evm.png)
above image continued image1
image3:    [image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaKd3.png)
above image continued image2
image4:   [image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StEue.png)
above image continued image3

I want to access all the values inside the products
like products have childs color,description,pic1,pic2,price
and in each child there are multiple values stored I want to access all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you already get the value. You can do like this, more apprioriate.

```
databaseReference.child("color").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){
         final String key= ds.getKey();
         final String pname= ds.getValue(String.class);
         Log.d("talha5",pname);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
       Log.e("color","Error: " + error.getMessage());
   }
});
```

Also, you need to handle `onCancelled`. Try to make as best practice.

UPDATE:

If you have many child. you need to separate them.

```
databaseReference.child("description").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){
         final String key= ds.getKey();
         final String pname= ds.getValue(String.class);
         Log.d("description",pname);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
       Log.e("description","Error: " + error.getMessage());
   }
});
```

Same goes to the others

```
databaseReference.child("pic1").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){
         final String key= ds.getKey();
         final String pname= ds.getValue(String.class);
         Log.d("pic1",pname);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
       Log.e("pic1","Error: " + error.getMessage());
   }
});
```

Comment: What if products have more child like color and I want to access all of them

Comment: @Talha I don't understand your question. Can you elobrate more ?

Comment: please check the question i edited , thanks